# Centering image captions in the Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using Wordpress 5.2.2 with the Gutenberg editor. When adding images the captions are always left-aligned irrespective as to whether the image itself is left, right or centered. I simply want my caption text centered under the images.

This is easy enough to sort out in pure html/css, but not within Gutenberg it seems.
My workaround is to insert a "Classic" block in Gutenberg and insert the image from the media button there.

Is there a better way, something I am missing or is this a shortcoming of Gutenberg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually theme-dependent, in the 2019 theme the captions are always centered by default. Why not set the `text-align` property of the `figcaption` element to `center` in your CSS?